# After updating array, View not updating

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript

Initially my user collection is
**Model:1**

```
  {
    "_id":"sodjflkadkjj2342",
    "role:["customer"],
    "active":true,
    "email":"chris@abc.com",
    "password":"$2a$10$RsemeECS8vCEav/CPgO75ucr5C2e3ybplnMShchlDKn6naUcEI0uW",
    "pwd_token":1502,
    "phone":1234567890
    }
```

I am updating it. Now it's now like
**Model 1.1**

```
 {
    "_id":"sodjflkadkjj2342",
    "role:["customer","employee"],
    "active":true,
    "email":"chris@abc.com",
    "password":"$2a$10$RsemeECS8vCEav/CPgO75ucr5C2e3ybplnMShchlDKn6naUcEI0uW",
    "pwd_token":1502,
    "phone":1234567890
    }
```

I could get this details via postman wit an API but from client I could get only **Model 1** as response

**Client**

```
  getUserDetails(token): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(environment.apiBase+'/api/user/get',{
      headers: {
        Authotization: token
      }
    });
  };
```

**TS**

```
  getUsers() {
    this.userService.getUserDetails(this.token).subscribe(
        data =>{this.users = data,
         console.log(this.users);
      },
      error => console.log(error),
    );
  }
```

Comment: have the result updated in view/template side?

Comment: No, Its not displaying the updated one. when I logout and login then It's showing updated one

Comment: Yes, for that you need to trigger API to update the result, instead of login/logout

Comment: you should call getUsers twice.

Comment: I triggered that API, I got only unupdated model as response  @PardeepJain

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses **zone.js** to detect changes in SPA. So, if you are changing data from Angular APP and if it's successfully changes in DB than probably you are not calling **getUsers()** (You have to call it again) to change your local data or more precisely your Array or something you have used. If it's not problem than please submit more code that we can see and help you out!